# Child Component not updating when parent updates vuejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue instance that passes an object to a child component.  The child component has a checkbox that when clicked calls an event that the vue instance handles to update the object on the parent that is passed to the child component.  Based on the [vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components) I thought this would cause the child component to update the related fields.  However, the date field is not updating as I would expect when I click on the checkbox.  In the image below, when I check the Management Name checkbox, I would expect the current day to appear, but I am not seeing any date.  What am I missing here?

### Design

[image: Layout of Child Component]

### Parent Instance

```
new Vue({
    el: "#evaluations-app",
    data: {
        evaluation: new Evaluation()        
    },
    methods: {        
        updateEmployeeSO: function (newSO, newSODate) {
            this.evaluation.EmployeeSO = newSO;
            this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate = newSODate;
        },
        updateReviewerSO: function (newSO, newSODate) {
            this.evaluation.ReviewerSO = newSO;
            this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate = newSODate;
        },
        updateManagementSO: function (newSO, newSODate) {
            this.evaluation.ManagementSO = newSO;
            this.evaluation.ManagementSODate = newSODate;
        }
});
```

### Child Component

```
Vue.component('sign-off', {
    props: ['initEvaluation', 'perspective'],
    template: `
        <div class="sign-off-comp">
            <div class="sign-off-item">
                <div class="sign-off-field-1 col-1">{{evaluation.EmployeeName}}</div>
                <input :disabled="!enableEmployeeSO" v-model="evaluation.EmployeeSO" class="sign-off-field-2 col-2" type="checkbox" @click="EmployeeSOChanged"/>
                <div class="sign-off-field-3 col-3">{{employeeSODate}}</div>                
            </div>  
            <div class="sign-off-item">
                <div class="sign-off-field-1 col-1">{{evaluation.ReviewerName}}</div>
                <input :disabled="!enableReviewerSO" v-model="evaluation.ReviewerSO" class="sign-off-field-2 col-2" type="checkbox" @click="ReviewerSOChanged"/>
                <div class="sign-off-field-3 col-3">{{reviewerSODate}}</div>                
            </div>   
            <div class="sign-off-item">
                <div class="sign-off-field-1 col-1">{{evaluation.ManagementName}}</div>
                <input :disabled="!enableManagementSO" v-model="evaluation.ManagementSO" class="sign-off-field-2 col-2" type="checkbox" @click="ManagementSOChanged"/>
                <div class="sign-off-field-3 col-3">{{managementSODate}}</div>                
            </div>                   
        </div>
    `,
    data: function () {
        return {
            evaluation: this.initEvaluation,
            employeeClicked: false,
            reviewerClicked: false,
            managementClicked: false,
            currentCommentSource: this.perspective
        }
    },
    methods: {
        EmployeeSOChanged: function () {
            this.employeeClicked = true;
            //this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate == null || this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate == "" ? this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate = Helpers.getCurrentDate() : this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate = "";
            this.$emit('employee-so-changed', this.evaluation.EmployeeSO, this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate);
        },
        ReviewerSOChanged: function () {
            this.reviewerClicked = true;
            //this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate == null || this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate == "" ? this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate = Helpers.getCurrentDate() : this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate = "";
            this.$emit('reviewer-so-changed', this.evaluation.ReviewerSO, this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate);
        },
        ManagementSOChanged: function () {
            this.managementClicked = true;
            //this.evaluation.ManagementSODate == null || this.evaluation.ManagementSODate == "" ? this.evaluation.ManagementSODate = Helpers.getCurrentDate() : this.evaluation.ManagementSODate = "";
            this.$emit('management-so-changed', this.evaluation.ManagementSO, this.evaluation.ManagementSODate == null || this.evaluation.ManagementSODate == "" ? Helpers.getCurrentDate() : "");
        }
    },
    computed: {
        enableEmployeeSO: function () {
            return (this.perspective == "Employee" && !this.evaluation.EmployeeSO) || this.employeeClicked;
        },
        enableReviewerSO: function () {
            return (this.perspective == "Reviewer" && !this.evaluation.ReviewerSO && this.evaluation.EmployeeSO) || this.reviewerClicked;
        },
        enableManagementSO: function () {
            return (this.perspective == "Management" && !this.evaluation.ManagementSO && this.evaluation.ReviewerSO && this.evaluation.EmployeeSO) || this.managementClicked;
        },
        employeeSODate: function () {
            return this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate != null && this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate == new Date("01-01-1900") ? "" : this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate != null && this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate.length >= 10 ? this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate.substring(0, 10) : this.evaluation.EmployeeSODate;
        },
        reviewerSODate: function () {
            return this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate != null && this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate == new Date("01-01-1900") ? "" : this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate != null && this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate.length >= 10 ? this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate.substring(0, 10) : this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate;
        },
        managementSODate: function () {
            return this.evaluation.ManagementSODate != null && this.evaluation.ManagementSODate == new Date("01-01-1900") ? "" : this.evaluation.ManagementSODate != null && this.evaluation.ManagementSODate.length >= 10 ? this.evaluation.ManagementSODate.substring(0, 10) : this.evaluation.ManagementSODate;
        }
    }
});
```

### Model

```
export class Evaluation {
    private _EmployeeName: string;
    private _EmployeeSO: boolean;
    private _EmployeeSODate: Date;
    private _ReviewerName: string;
    private _ReviewerSO: boolean;
    private _ReviewerSODate: Date;
    private _ManagementReviewerName: string;
    private _ManagementReviewerSO: boolean;
    private _ManagementReviewerSODate: Date;

    constructor() {
        this._EmployeeName = "";
        this._EmployeeSO = false;
        this._EmployeeSODate = new Date("01-01-1900");
        this._ReviewerName = "";
        this._ReviewerSO = false;
        this._ReviewerSODate = new Date("01-01-1900");
        this._ManagementReviewerName = "";
        this._ManagementReviewerSO = false;
        this._ManagementReviewerSODate = new Date("01-01-1900");
    }

    get EmployeeName(): string {
        return this._EmployeeName;
    }
    set EmployeeName(employeeName: string) {
        if (this._EmployeeName != employeeName) {
            this._EmployeeName = employeeName;
        }
    }
   
    get EmployeeSO(): boolean {
        return this._EmployeeSO;
    }
    set EmployeeSO(employeeSO: boolean) {
        if (this._EmployeeSO != employeeSO) {
            this._EmployeeSO = employeeSO;
        }
    }

    get EmployeeSODate(): Date {
        return this._EmployeeSODate;
    }
    set EmployeeSODate(employeeSODate: Date) {
        if (this._EmployeeSODate != employeeSODate) {
            this._EmployeeSODate = employeeSODate;
        }
    }

    get ReviewerName(): string {
        return this._ReviewerName;
    }
    set ReviewerName(reviewerName: string) {
        if (this._ReviewerName != reviewerName) {
            this._ReviewerName = reviewerName;
        }
    }

    get ReviewerSO(): boolean {
        return this._ReviewerSO;
    }
    set ReviewerSO(reviewerSO: boolean) {
        if (this._ReviewerSO != reviewerSO) {
            this._ReviewerSO = reviewerSO;
        }
    }

    get ReviewerSODate(): Date {
        return this._ReviewerSODate;
    }
    set ReviewerSODate(reviewerSODate: Date) {
        if (this._ReviewerSODate != reviewerSODate) {
            this._ReviewerSODate = reviewerSODate;
        }
    }

    get ManagementReviewerName(): string {
        return this._ManagementReviewerName;
    }
    set ManagementReviewerName(managementReviewerName: string) {
        if (this._ManagementReviewerName != managementReviewerName) {
            this._ManagementReviewerName = managementReviewerName;
        }
    }

    get ManagementReviewerSO(): boolean {
        return this._ManagementReviewerSO;
    }
    set ManagementReviewerSO(managementReviewerSO: boolean) {
        if (this._ManagementReviewerSO != managementReviewerSO) {
            this._ManagementReviewerSO = managementReviewerSO;
        }
    }

    get ManagementReviewerSODate(): Date {
        return this._ManagementReviewerSODate;
    }
    set ManagementReviewerSODate(managementReviewerSODate: Date) {
        if (this._ManagementReviewerSODate != managementReviewerSODate) {
            this._ManagementReviewerSODate = managementReviewerSODate;
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

I just noticed that in my child component I am using `MangementSO` & `ManagementSODate` while the model has `ManagementReviewerSO` & `ManagementReviewerSODate`.  Changing these fixes my code.  However, based on discussion below, I am a little confused as to why putting props into the local data is the incorrect way to handle this situation.  Can someone please explain?

Comment: do not store passed down properties in data function,
instead of `evaluation.ReviewerName` just use `initEvaluation.ReviewerName`.

Comment: @AndreyKudriavtsev  Why should I avoid storing passed down properties?  In this case I'm changing both the [type]SO and [type]SODate fields in the child component.  If I don't store these in data then I would be updating the props which would throw an error according to the documentation.

Comment: because you breaks 'reactiveness' of that properties. Instead using local data, you should use properties directly, right in your methods and computed properties, just like you using your `this.evaluation.ReviewerSODate` use `this.initEvaluation.ReviewerSODate`. You do not lose any thing, just replace one variable to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with *initializing* data properties with props. I think the biggest source of confusion in a lot of the comments here is the fact that `initEvaluation` is an *object*. That being the case, any changes to that object will be reflected *everywhere* that the object is used.

In the code in question, `evaluation` in the parent component, and `evaluation` in the child component *are the same object*. Changes made to that object *will* be reflected in the parent and there will no *no* complaint on Vue's part because you are not technically mutating the reference to the object, you are just changing values of it's *properties*.

Generally, where Vue will throw a warning is if you pass a *primitive* value as a property. Lets say you passed a string value and then you used that value with `v-model`. In *that* case, Vue will throw a warning (in the development version) that you are mutating a property. There are two reasons for the warning; first because that value is *not* propagated to the parent (which is likely unexpected behavior), and second, because whenever the data is changed in the *parent* it will overwrite changes in the child.

When an object or array is passed as a property, however, Vue will only complain if you change the object reference. For example in your code if you were to do this:

```
this.initEvaluation = new Evaluation()
```

Vue would complain that you are mutating a property. In your code, however you are simply changing the *properties* of `initEvaluation` and this does not result in a warning, and also results in those values being reflected *everywhere* because you are updating the *same* object everywhere.

One of the ramifications of this, is that effectively in your code, setting `evaluation: this.initEvaluation` is spurious. You *could* use `initEvaluation` in your template and get the same results as using `evaluation`. Again, this is because they are the *same* object. This is part of what Luiz is attempting to explain. Luiz's first sentence is slightly misleading in this case. The data function is only called *once* which means that data initialized with properties will only receive the value of the property once. However, because `initEvaluation` is an object, it doesn't really matter in the question's code. The object *reference* never changes, only the properties do. If the parent were to *change* the reference for some reason, `evaluation` in the child would *not* be updated with the new *reference*.

Whether or not updates being immediately reflected everywhere for an object is *desirable* is debatable. In many cases you want to control *when* updates occur. In those cases you might do something like `evaluation: Object.assign({}, this.initEvaluation)` which makes a *copy* of the `initEvaluation` object. The advanatage of doing this is you can make as many changes as you want to the object in the child component without those changes being reflected *outside* the component. Then, after you have validated all the changes are correct, you can *emit* those changes.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `data` properties based on the `props` (`initEvaluation` and `perspective`), they no longer depend on the props and you're exclusively referencing the data, as if they were simply copies, but not the actual props received. So, they don't react on the props.

Since you don't seem to be updating them in the component, you could just reference the `props` directly, instead of the `data` created from the `props`.

EDIT: Scratch that, you're using `v-model` on `evaluation` so you'd change the prop if you referenced them directly.

So, in general, I would remove this from data:

```
evaluation: this.initEvaluation
// ...
currentCommentSource: this.perspective
```

And reference the `props` directly, and replace `v-model` with `:value` and `@input`, as recommended in the docs.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be accurate in my experience. I have passed down properties and saved them into data in the past and have seen changes to the props when the parents' data was updated.  In fact, I just realized on this question that I had a misspelling which when fixed shows this behavior.

Comment: Yes, the props change when the parent's data is updated. But you're not using the props anywhere, when you assign them to properties in data, that data itself is not reactive on the props, so the props may change, but the data derived from the props doesn't. This is expected behavior in vue

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing.  Check out my updated question.  When I change `ManagementSO` to `ManagementReviewerSO` and `ManagementSODate` to `ManagementReviewerSODate` everything works correctly which seems to contradict what you are saying.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/luord/pen/ayzWeL) for an example. But if it's working correctly now, then maybe vue keeps the references when it's a fat object what's returned in data. Interesting, I'll recheck the documentation on  that.